# IIS Delegation suddenly stopped working Windows Server 2016 running SqlPackage.exe to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, iis, deployment, teamcity, delegation

### Background

We use Team City to deploy our web sites and SQL migrations/dacpac's to servers that have been working successfully for quite some time. One of our servers was last deployed to on 4 March 2019.

Today I did a deploy to that server and our step that deploys dacpac and migrations has stopped working on that server.

The server is Windows Server 2016 environments, running Sql Server 2017 with all the latest windows patches.

We are using IIS Delegation (**NOT using Kerberos**).

### I can confirm the following

- Nothing has changed in terms of IIS Settings, user permissions or
  anything on this server
- The last successful release out to the server was 4 March 2019.
- The last time anyone logged onto this server was February 2019
- Pre-authenticating to remote agent URL
  'https://devdeploy.mydomain:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=mysite' as
  'TeamCity' authenticates as expected
- The delegation set up is as follows: [image: Delegation Settings]

### The step that is now failing looks like this

run a .bat file that has the following command:

`WHOAMI`

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"C:\inetpub\websitepath\dacpac\mydacpac.dacpac" /TargetServerName:SQLServer /TargetDatabaseName:MyDatabase
```

(NOTE: The `WHOAMI` This returns "ServerName\TeamCity")

***The error given in Team City logs is:***

> Cannot open database "MyDatabase" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'ServerName\TeamCity'.

This implies (IMHO) that the delegation from IIS to the batch file which is run, is no longer occurring.

It appears that IIS Delegation has not performed the correct delegation and is running the user under the 'TeamCity' not under the delegated user 'DbOwnerUser' (see image above for runCommand delegation setup).

### My Questions therefore are

- Is anyone else having this issue?
- Is there a security update that has caused this to no longer work
  e.g. [KB4489885](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4489885/windows-7-update-kb4489885) (this talks about Kerberos and we are NOT using
  Kerberos)
- Does anyone have any thoughts as to how this could happen or be fixed
  (apart from uninstalling the security update)?

Thanks in advance to anyone who has some good ideas :)